# Sort three string arrays using maps

Tags: java, android

I could sort two arrays simultaneously using the following code, but now I need to add a new one. So I need to sort 3 arrays simultaneously .iceStringArray contains words, engStringArray contains their translation, soundStringArray contains their audio file title. I'm trying to sort iceStringArray alphabetically with the other two arrays respecting that orther. This code works perfectly with two arrays, but I struggle to find a way to add a new one

```
        Map<String, String> myLocalMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (int indx = 0; indx < iceStringArray.length; indx++) {
            myLocalMap.put(iceStringArray[indx], engStringArray[indx]);
        }

        Arrays.sort(iceStringArray);

        for (int indx = 0; indx < iceStringArray.length; indx++) {
            engStringArray[indx] = myLocalMap.get(iceStringArray[indx]);

        }

        // soundStringList is the new array  I want to add
        lAdapter = new ListAdapter(TrainingActivity.this, iceStringArray, engStringArray, soundStringList);
        lView.setAdapter(lAdapter);
```

Comment: Don't sort arrays in parallel, use objects.

Answer (score 2):

You can store the mapping of `iceStringArray` values to their indexes before sort and then use the indexes to align the other arrays.

```
Map<String, Integer> myLocalMap = new HashMap<>();
for (int indx = 0; indx < iceStringArray.length; indx++) {
    myLocalMap.put(iceStringArray[indx], indx);
}
```

And then after sort:

```
// Create new temp arrays
String[] sortedEngStringArray = new String[iceStringArray.length];
String[] sortedSoundStringArray = new String[iceStringArray.length];

for (int indx = 0; indx < iceStringArray.length; indx++) {
    sortedEngStringArray[indx] = engStringArray[myLocalMap.get(iceStringArray[indx])];
    sortedSoundStringArray[indx] = soundStringArray[myLocalMap.get(iceStringArray[indx])];
}
```

Comment: I don't completely get how to add the third array, sorry. When you say // the same for the third array what do you mean, because the closest as I got is to add                 engStringArray[indx] = engStringArray[myLocalMap.get(iceStringArray[indx])];
 there

Comment: @CroquetaFregidaAmbPastanaga Added

Answer (score 0):

Its a clear case of one-to-one mapping

So we can have a Class which encapsulates data of English Translation & Sound

```
class Data{
    String translation;
    String sound;

    //have getter setters for these
}
```

Now you can have an array of this, being iterated with `iceStringArray`